# Problem with \vline in tabular

Tags: tables, line, vertical

is there a way to have the solution in the figure? without \multicolumn{}{} in every number? Thanks[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layaureo}%impagina meglio le pagine, pacchetto grafico su 
sezione aurea
\usepackage{emptypage} % non numera le pagine vuote con opzione openright
\usepackage{setspace} %modifica interlinea
  \usepackage{float}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\usepackage{multirow}%tabelle multiriga
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}%To keep spacing of text in tables
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{lSSS|SSSSSS}
    \toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014h1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014h2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015h1} \\
    & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} \\
\midrule
A     & 0.02  & 0.02  & 0.02  & 0.23  & 0.24  & 0.23  & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.69 \\
B     & 0.03  & 0.05  & 0.04  & 0.27  & 0.47  & 0.38  & 0.90  & 1.30  & 1.05 \\
C     & 0.06  & 0.14  & 0.11  & 0.50  & 0.83  & 0.63  & 1.37  & 2.03  & 1.72 \\
D     & 0.14  & 0.32  & 0.23  & 0.83  & 1.37  & 1.00  & 2.07  & 3.19  & 2.54 \\
E     & 0.32  & 0.74  & 0.52  & 1.47  & 2.49  & 2.11  & 3.22  & 4.95  & 4.31 \\
F     & 0.75  & 1.72  & 1.23  & 2.60  & 4.56  & 2.95  & 5.00  & 7.49  & 6.37 \\
G     & 1.75  & 3.99  & 2.78  & 5.12  & 7.88  & 6.55  & 7.86  & 11.54 & 8.90 \\
H     & 4.00  & 9.11  & 5.34  & 8.17  & 14.12 & 9.09  & 12.62 & 17.73 & 13.12 \\
I     & 9.30  & 20.86 & 13.77 & 15.04 & 23.62 & 17.85 & 19.64 & 28.57 & 24.81 \\
L     & 22.05 & 47.93 & 35.87 & 31.39 & 44.02 & 38.72 & 29.73 & 40.98 & 35.17 \\
&       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\midrule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015h2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2016h1} &       &       &  \\
& {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-7}
A     & 0.30  & 0.33  & 0.31  & 0.05  & 0.08  & 0.08  &       &       &  \\
B     & 0.48  & 0.57  & 0.55  & 0.10  & 0.14  & 0.11  &       &       &  \\
C     & 0.69  & 0.96  & 0.95  & 0.16  & 0.30  & 0.27  &       &       &  \\
D     & 1.12  & 1.67  & 1.53  & 0.33  & 0.64  & 0.46  &       &       &  \\
E     & 1.88  & 2.60  & 2.51  & 0.65  & 1.27  & 0.86  &       &       &  \\
F     & 2.80  & 3.80  & 3.02  & 1.31  & 2.55  & 2.15  &       &       &  \\
G     & 5.38  & 6.27  & 5.74  & 2.60  & 5.06  & 3.19  &       &       &  \\
H     & 7.78  & 10.46 & 9.92  & 5.50  & 9.31  & 6.02  &       &       &  \\
I     & 12.48 & 16.52 & 16.26 & 10.98 & 17.48 & 14.54 &       &       &  \\
L     & 18.74 & 29.69 & 28.42 & 21.46 & 38.41 & 31.45 &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-7}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two tabulars:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layaureo}%impagina meglio le pagine, pacchetto grafico su sezione aurea
\usepackage{emptypage} % non numera le pagine vuote con opzione openright
\usepackage{setspace} %modifica interlinea
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\usepackage{multirow}%tabelle multiriga
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}%To keep spacing of text in tables
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{lSSS|SSS|SSS}\toprule
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2014h1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2014h2} & 
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015h1} \\
            & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} & {PD 
            min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} \\
            \midrule
            A     & 0.02  & 0.02  & 0.02  & 0.23  & 0.24  & 0.23  & 0.69  & 0.84  & 0.69 
            \\
            B     & 0.03  & 0.05  & 0.04  & 0.27  & 0.47  & 0.38  & 0.90  & 1.30  & 1.05 
            \\
            C     & 0.06  & 0.14  & 0.11  & 0.50  & 0.83  & 0.63  & 1.37  & 2.03  & 1.72 
            \\
            D     & 0.14  & 0.32  & 0.23  & 0.83  & 1.37  & 1.00  & 2.07  & 3.19  & 2.54 
            \\
            E     & 0.32  & 0.74  & 0.52  & 1.47  & 2.49  & 2.11  & 3.22  & 4.95  & 4.31 
            \\
            F     & 0.75  & 1.72  & 1.23  & 2.60  & 4.56  & 2.95  & 5.00  & 7.49  & 6.37 
            \\
            G     & 1.75  & 3.99  & 2.78  & 5.12  & 7.88  & 6.55  & 7.86  & 11.54 & 8.90 
            \\
            H     & 4.00  & 9.11  & 5.34  & 8.17  & 14.12 & 9.09  & 12.62 & 17.73 & 13.12 
            \\
            I     & 9.30  & 20.86 & 13.77 & 15.04 & 23.62 & 17.85 & 19.64 & 28.57 & 24.81 
            \\
            L     & 22.05 & 47.93 & 35.87 & 31.39 & 44.02 & 38.72 & 29.73 & 40.98 & 35.17 
            \\
            &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
            \midrule
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lSSS|SSSSSS}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2015h2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2016h1} &       &       
            &  
            \\
            & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} & {PD min} & {PD max} & {PD classe} 
            &       &       &  \\
            \cmidrule{1-7}
            A     & 0.30  & 0.33  & 0.31  & 0.05  & 0.08  & 0.08  &       &       &  \\
            B     & 0.48  & 0.57  & 0.55  & 0.10  & 0.14  & 0.11  &       &       &  \\
            C     & 0.69  & 0.96  & 0.95  & 0.16  & 0.30  & 0.27  &       &       &  \\
            D     & 1.12  & 1.67  & 1.53  & 0.33  & 0.64  & 0.46  &       &       &  \\
            E     & 1.88  & 2.60  & 2.51  & 0.65  & 1.27  & 0.86  &       &       &  \\
            F     & 2.80  & 3.80  & 3.02  & 1.31  & 2.55  & 2.15  &       &       &  \\
            G     & 5.38  & 6.27  & 5.74  & 2.60  & 5.06  & 3.19  &       &       &  \\
            H     & 7.78  & 10.46 & 9.92  & 5.50  & 9.31  & 6.02  &       &       &  \\
            I     & 12.48 & 16.52 & 16.26 & 10.98 & 17.48 & 14.54 &       &       &  \\
            L     & 18.74 & 29.69 & 28.42 & 21.46 & 38.41 & 31.45 &       &       &  \\
            \cmidrule{1-7}
\end{tabular}%
\end{varwidth}
\end{sidewaystable}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't taught at the simplier solution at all

Answer (score 0):

You need no vertical rule at all, if you organize better your table. Moreover, you don't even have to rotate it by reducing the horizontal size, which can be achieved by setting aside the common parts (PD, in this case). The horizontal broken rules will make clear that the table is split every three columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{layaureo}

\usepackage{rotating,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{9}{S[table-format=2.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014h1}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014h2}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015h1}
\\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{PD}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{PD}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{PD}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& {min} & {max} & {classe}
& {min} & {max} & {classe}
& {min} & {max} & {classe}
\\
\midrule
A &  0.02 &  0.02 &  0.02 &  0.23 &  0.24 &  0.23 &  0.69 &  0.84 &  0.69 \\
B &  0.03 &  0.05 &  0.04 &  0.27 &  0.47 &  0.38 &  0.90 &  1.30 &  1.05 \\
C &  0.06 &  0.14 &  0.11 &  0.50 &  0.83 &  0.63 &  1.37 &  2.03 &  1.72 \\
D &  0.14 &  0.32 &  0.23 &  0.83 &  1.37 &  1.00 &  2.07 &  3.19 &  2.54 \\
E &  0.32 &  0.74 &  0.52 &  1.47 &  2.49 &  2.11 &  3.22 &  4.95 &  4.31 \\
F &  0.75 &  1.72 &  1.23 &  2.60 &  4.56 &  2.95 &  5.00 &  7.49 &  6.37 \\
G &  1.75 &  3.99 &  2.78 &  5.12 &  7.88 &  6.55 &  7.86 & 11.54 &  8.90 \\
H &  4.00 &  9.11 &  5.34 &  8.17 & 14.12 &  9.09 & 12.62 & 17.73 & 13.12 \\
I &  9.30 & 20.86 & 13.77 & 15.04 & 23.62 & 17.85 & 19.64 & 28.57 & 24.81 \\
L & 22.05 & 47.93 & 35.87 & 31.39 & 44.02 & 38.72 & 29.73 & 40.98 & 35.17 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015h2}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{2016h1}
\\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{PD}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{PD}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
& {min} & {max} & {classe}
& {min} & {max} & {classe}
\\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-7}
A &  0.30 &  0.33 &  0.31 &  0.05 &  0.08 &  0.08 \\
B &  0.48 &  0.57 &  0.55 &  0.10 &  0.14 &  0.11 \\
C &  0.69 &  0.96 &  0.95 &  0.16 &  0.30 &  0.27 \\
D &  1.12 &  1.67 &  1.53 &  0.33 &  0.64 &  0.46 \\
E &  1.88 &  2.60 &  2.51 &  0.65 &  1.27 &  0.86 \\
F &  2.80 &  3.80 &  3.02 &  1.31 &  2.55 &  2.15 \\
G &  5.38 &  6.27 &  5.74 &  2.60 &  5.06 &  3.19 \\
H &  7.78 & 10.46 &  9.92 &  5.50 &  9.31 &  6.02 \\
I & 12.48 & 16.52 & 16.26 & 10.98 & 17.48 & 14.54 \\
L & 18.74 & 29.69 & 28.42 & 21.46 & 38.41 & 31.45 \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-7}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]